# Let $a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+a_{n}}{2}}$ show that $0 \leq a_{n} \leq 1$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Let $0 \leq a_{1} \leq 1$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+a_{n}}{2}}$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Show that:

**(a)** $0 \leq a_{n} \leq 1$ for all n.

**(b)** $ a_{n+1} \geq a_{n}$ for all n.

I don't know if the following is correct.

My attempt.

By using induction:

**(a)** Show that $0 \leq a_{n} \leq 1$ for all n.

We have $0 \leq a_{1} \leq 1$ and we want to show that $0 \leq a_{2} \leq 1$ for all n.

$0 \leq a_{1} \leq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{a_{1}+1}{2} \leq 1 \Rightarrow  \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}} \leq  \sqrt[3]{\frac{a_{1}+1}{2}}  \leq \sqrt[3]1 \Rightarrow 0.8 \leq a_{2} \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq a_{2} \leq 1 $

Now we suppose that the relation is true for n.

We want to show that it is also true for n+1.

We have:

$0 \leq a_{n} \leq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{a_{n}+1}{2} \leq 1 \Rightarrow  \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}} \leq  \sqrt[3]{\frac{a_{n}+1}{2}}  \leq \sqrt[3]1 \Rightarrow 0.8 \leq a_{n+1} \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq a_{n+1} \leq 1 $

**(b)** Show that $ a_{n+1} \geq a_{n}$ for all n.

$ a_{n+1} \geq a_{n} \Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{\frac{1+a_{n}}{2}} \geq a_{n} \Rightarrow 1+a_{n} \geq 2a_{n}^3$

This is true because we know that $0 \leq a_{n} \leq 1$ and that $ a_{n} \geq a_{n}^3$.

Comment: This looks good.(If this is for school, then depending on your teacher, you might want to add a few minor statements explaining why some of these inequality implications are true.) Minor typo with "we want to show that $ 0 \leq a_2 \leq 1 $ for all $n$ ".

Comment: For$(b)$ did you leave out the base case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a) you don't need to prove the statement for $a_2$.

You can simplify the argument by proving first that $a_n\ge0$. This is true for $a_1$; suppose it is true for $a_n$; then $a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{(a_n+1)/2}\ge0$.

Now the other inequality, which you did well: if $a_n\le1$, then $(a_n+1)/2\le1$ and therefore $a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{(a_n+1)/2}\le1$.

For (b) the arrows are in the wrong direction! You need to prove that $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$ and you can't take this as an assumption. However
$$
a_{n+1}\ge a_n
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
a_{n+1}^3\ge a_n^3
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
\frac{a_{n}+1}{2}\ge a_n^3
$$
so we are reduced to proving that $2a_n^3\le a_n+1$.

Your argument is fine: $a_n\le1$ implies $a_n^3\le a_n$ and $a_n^3\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $(b)$ it doesnt look like you've shown the base case nor the implication that if $a_{n+1} \geq a_{n}$, then $a_{n+2} \geq a_{n+1}$. All you did was reach a true statement...

I see what you have done now, but it is less obvious that you are meaning to say that since these steps are reversible, the inequality is satisfied.

I would still write out that you have reversible steps, or even start your implications starting at $1+a_{n} \geq 2{{a_n}^3}$ and showing this is true since by the inequalities you have listed we have $1+ a_{n} \geq a_{n}+a_{n}=2a_{n} \geq 2a^3_{n}$. It looks like your way might be a bit better because it follows directly from proving the base case in my proof.

I did it a different way:

Suppose $a_{n+1} \geq a_{n}$ is true for some $n$ (it is clear from the previous work this works for $n=1$).

Then $a_{n+2} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{1+a_{n+1}}{2}} \geq? \sqrt[3]{\frac{1+a_{n}}{2}} = a_{n+1}$ which is true by the inductive hypothesis.

In fact, the base case for $(b)$ might not be so clear without using your inequality anyways.